# File URI removing hostname path during a resolve operation

Tags: java, uri

I have a resource that has been opened by using a File URL to load from a network share on the Windows network, e.g. `file:////remotemachine/my/path/spec.txt`.

This file specifies a path to another resource that I have to load. I use the `URI.resolve(String)` method to create a URI to this resource. This is causing a problem because the newly create File resource doesn't contain the necessary slahses to indicate the remotehost. Instead of

```
file:////remotemachine/my/path/data.dat
```

I get

```
file:///remotemachine/my/path/data.dat
```

The missing slash means the file is trying to be loaded from the local machine where the resource doesn't exist (nor does the path).

This does the same thing if I use IP addresses instead of machine names. If I use a mapped file name, e.g. `file:///M:/path/spec.txt` then the resource file correctly resolves to `file:///M:/path/data.dat`. Also if I use a http protocol path the URI resolves correctly.

Can anyone identify if I have a misunderstanding in resolving File URIs again network shares of if this is a bug in Java?

The relevant section of code

```
private Tile(URI documentBase, XPath x, Node n) throws XPathExpressionException, IOException
{
  String imagePath = (String) x.evaluate("FileName", n, XPathConstants.STRING);
  this.imageURL = documentBase.resolve(imagePath).toURL();
}
```

**Update**

I've come up with a fix for my problem

```
private Tile(URI documentBase, XPath x, Node n) throws XPathExpressionException, IOException
{
  boolean isRemoteHostFile = documentBase.getScheme().equals("file") &&
                             documentBase.getPath().startsWith("//");

  String imagePath = (String) x.evaluate("FileName", n, XPathConstants.STRING);
  imageURL = documentBase.resolve(imagePath).toURL();
  if ( isRemoteHostFile )
  {
    imageURL = new URL(imageURL.getProtocol()+":///"+imageURL.getPath());
  }
}
```

However I'm still curious if the File: thing is a Java bug, a URI problem or just a big misunderstanding of how it works on my part.

Comment: You're running into the crufty bits at the interface between sanity (UNIX-style paths) and insanity (Windows file-share paths)

Comment: I just found another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878024/file-uris-and-slashes) similar to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe 'file://remotemachine/my/path/data.dat'? Two slashes, not four.