# How to upload artifact to network drive using gradle?

Tags: upload, gradle, fileshare

I am reading this:

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_management.html

to understand how to publish/upload my artifact to a network drive/fileshare which is a requirement (we have a maven repo up and running but some artifacts needs to be dumped on a fileshare). The examples I have found are more focused on deploying to repositories, maven, ivy, etc.

I have a simple eclipse java project that I build using gradle 1.2 with the following build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java' 

sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir 'src'
    }
  }
  test {
    java {
      srcDir 'test'
    }
  }
}
repositories {
  flatDir {
      name "fileRepo"
      dirs "file://internal.newtwork.drive/folder/test"
  }
}

uploadArchives {
  repositories {
      add project.repositories.fileRepo
  }
}
```

Where in the gradle docs can I read about how to copy resources to a remote fileshare?

I have tried to update the protocol and the dir attribute based on the below answers but I get this error:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':uploadArchives'.

> Could not publish configuration ':archives'.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /internal.newtwork.drive/folder/test/sample-gradle-java-unspecified.jar (No such file or directory)
>   
>   The destination is correct so does the flatDir repo not support networkdrives?

Answer (score 1):

You should  define the following parameters:

```
archivesBaseName = 'yourappname'
group = 'your.app.package'
version = '1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL doesn't mention a scheme (http:, file:, etc.). I don't know if you can get away with using a file: URL, or whether you need to us a different syntax to specify a directory rather than an HTTP URL, but either way, you'll need to correctly form the URI for the Windows UNC path.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878024/file-uris-and-slashes) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're crossing your wires.  The url would only be part of that ivy repository declaration which you're apparently not using.  The filesystem repository would be handled by the flatDir block which is then referenced by the `add project.repositories.fileRepo` statement.  I'd suggest trying the full path in the flatDir `dir` variable, otherwise the path of least resistance may just be to throw together a simple manual file copy (or other transfer) task which is then added on to the main deploy task you're using.

Comment: I have now tried what you suggested, see above. But still get an error.

Answer (score 0):

//Try this,

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories {
    maven {
        url "$archivaUrl"`enter code here`
    credentials {
            username = "$userName"
            password = "$passWord"
        }
    }
}

// Dependencies
dependencies { 
    // specify the lib files at compile and run time         
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['**/*.jar','*.jar'])
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['**/*.jar','*.jar'])
}


// source path 
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
        srcDirs 'src'
        }

    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
        repository(url: "$archivaUrl") {
        authentication(userName: "$userName", password: "$passWord")
        }
        pom.version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
        pom.artifactId = "fd-common"
        pom.groupId = "com.somename.common"
    }    

    }
}
```

Comment: #archivaurl is nothing but the url for apache archiva which will read from the propertie file ex:archivaurl= http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/internal  and the same goes for the authentication also.