# Using Gradle To Move Source Controlled Files Across Network

Tags: gradle

A project I'm working on uses Gradle to build code bases. I'm quite new to Gradle. I want to modify the current build process such that, once the build concludes, it moves a set of files (configuration files in this case), which are under source control (SVN), to a folder on another server on the network.

I've looked through the Gradle user guide, and have come across the 'copy' and 'sync' tasks. Will either of these be sufficient to carry out what I've described? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a remote repository and upload there like in [How to upload artifact to network drive using gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727783/how-to-upload-artifact-to-network-drive-using-gradle)

If that doesn't suit your need you can look for gradle-ssh-plugin or just write a task that will execute `scp` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll take a look as suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up creating a gradle script that employs the SCP Ant task, which satisfied my needs.