# Why would aFile.toURI().toString() on linux have a single slash?

Tags: java, linux, uri, file-uri

What is the deal with Java's bizarre file protocol handling?
I mean on windows UNC path's get turned into 5 slashes, and I get why that happens, but on linux an absolute path gets turned into `file:/local/path/to/file` 
Shouldn't that have three slashes?
I'm assuming the authors of Java aren't incompetent, so is there an explanation for why that's acceptable?

Comment: on windows UNC path's get turned into 5 slashes  - it's not true.

Comment: Maybe it's 4 slashes. I've definitely had java programs that wouldn't accept UNC with 2 slashes and would say "missing authority" Anyway that was a side issue. My main question is about single slash as opposed to triple

Comment: @MikeAdamenko https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878024/file-uris-and-slashes this was what I was referring to which might not have to do with aFile.toURI().toString()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s start with the [documentation of the URI class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html):

> A hierarchical URI is subject to further parsing according to the syntax
>
> [*scheme*`:`][`//`*authority*][*path*][`?`*query*][`#`*fragment*]

As you can see, the authority is optional.  This is supported by [the URI specification, section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3):

> The scheme and path components are required, though the path may be empty (no characters).  When authority is present, the path must either be empty or begin with a slash ("/") character.  When authority is not present, the path cannot begin with two slash characters ("//").

A `file:` URI *can* have an authority separator, `//`, with an effectively empty authority after it, but it serves no purpose, so there is no harm in omitting it. It’s still a fully compliant URI.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the document you linked to does not include the two slashes as part of the authority.

Comment: @Novaterata You’re right.  Updated last part of answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok, I found where there is evidence for the optionality of double slash. in the pseudocode here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-5.3 note that the append "//" would not occur if authority is not defined