# Why are there four slashes after file: when I call file.toURI() on a Windows share?

Tags: java, uri

Either

```
File share = new File("//myserver/folder");
```

or

```
File share = new File("\\\\myserver\\folder");

String shareURI = share.toURI().toString();
System.out.println(shareURI);
```

I'd have expected

file://myserver/folder

but got

file:////myserver/folder

Java 8 on Windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878024/file-uris-and-slashes This might be of help

Comment: Thanks! "Java is wrong" was my first thought, which I wouldn't dare to believe without asking other people.